# PayPal Payments Standard Authorization And Capture

Tags: paypal

I've been trying to set all PayPal payments to come through as "Authorization" and show as "pending" in our PayPal account, where we then have the option to either "void" or "capture" the funds from there. We've struggled with PayPal Express Checkout code, so are now looking at how we can achieve this with PayPal Standard.

We tried adding the following with no success: ‘payment_action’ => ‘authorization’ to $paypal_vars[].

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/wp-e-commerce/WP-e-Commerce/blob/branch-3.15.1/wpsc-merchants/paypal-standard.merchant.php#L120-L129

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For payments standard you need `paymentaction=authorization` in the request string ([see documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#shopping-cart-variables))

In PHP array syntax, `'paymentaction' => 'authorization',`

Comment: Thanks Preston, Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: Hi Preston, just a courtesy message to let you know that I've got this working. Thank you for all your help. Kind Regards, Andrew